# LinkedIn get profile feed or news feed 2015

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

I have created app in LinkedIn and I am trying to get profile feed or news feed but when requested network updates i got this message Access to network denied and I am unable to get scopes such as rw_nus .
please help me can i get any feed (profile feed or news feed ) from LinkedIn .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the May 15 changes. Please read up on that as rw_nus seems to require a special permission now for which you need to apply to become a API partner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11022330)

Comment: Becoming the API partner is the only way AFAIK to get what Ahmed wants to do. This is the correct answer. No?

Comment: @dinwal It is, reviewer just didn't took time to read the original question.